# Convergence of multiple zeta function

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The following term:$$\zeta(k_1,k_2,...,k_n)=\sum_{m_1>m_2>\cdots>m_n>0}\frac{1}{m_1^{k_1}m_2^{k_2}\cdots m_n^{k_n}}, m_i\in\mathbb{N}, k_i\in\mathbb{N}$$ is called the "multiple zeta value". How can one prove that it converges when $k_1>1$?

Comment: $$\sum_{m_1>m_2>\cdots>m_n>0}\frac{1}{m_1^{k_1}m_2^{k_2}\cdots m_n^{k_n}} \le \prod\limits_{j=1}^{n}\left(\sum\limits_{m_j > 0} \frac{1}{m_j^{k_j}}\right)$$ convergence follows by Convergence of $\zeta(k)$ for $k > 1$

Comment: @r9m sorry, it is $k_1>1$.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the following.

It is easy to see that $\zeta(k_1,k_2,\dots,k_n)$ converges for all natural $k_1>1$, $k_2$, ..., $k_n$ iff $\zeta(2,1,\dots,1)$ converges. But

$$\zeta(2,1,\dots,1)=\sum_{m_1>m_2>\cdots>m_n>0}\frac{1}{m_1^{2}m_2\cdots m_n}\le 
$$ $$\sum_{m_1\ge m_2, m_3, \cdots,m_n\ge 1}\frac{1}{m_1^{2}m_2\cdots m_n}=$$ $$ 
\sum_{m_1=1}^\infty \frac{1}{m_1^2}\left(\sum_{m=1}^{m_1}\frac 1m\right)^{n-1}\le 
\sum_{m_1=1}^\infty \frac{(1+\ln m_1)^{n-1}}{m_1^2}.$$

The last series converges because there exists a number $M$ such that $$(1+\ln m_1)^{n-1}m_1^{-2}< m_1^{-3/2}$$ for each $m_1>M$, and the series $\sum_{m_1=1}^\infty m_1^{-3/2}$ converges by majoration by a convergent integral $\int_1^{\infty}x^{-3/2}dx.$